# display categories based on custom attribute value

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes

i have added a boolean custom attribute for categories using the following code

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup;
$attribute  = array(
    'group'                => 'General',
    'type'              => 'int',//can be int, varchar, decimal, text, datetime
    'backend'           => '',
    'frontend_input'    => '',
    'frontend'          => '',
    'label'             => 'popular category',
    'input'             => 'select', //text, textarea, select, file, image, multilselect
    'default' => array(0),
    'class'             => '',
    'source'            => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',//this is necessary for select and multilelect, for the rest leave it blank
    'global'             => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,//scope can be SCOPE_STORE or SCOPE_GLOBAL or SCOPE_WEBSITE
    'visible'           => true,
    'frontend_class'     => '',
    'required'          => false,//or true
    'user_defined'      => true,
    'default'           => '',
    'position'            => 100,//any number will do
);

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'attribute_popular', $attribute);
$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

now i want to show the categories having the attribute value "yes" in home page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter category collection by below code

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_code_here', 'value_here');
```

In your case:

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_popular', 1)
        ->setPageSize(6)
        ->setCurPage(1);
```

Comment: i want to display 6 categories only

Comment: update answer check it